# How can I load a Gdiplus::Bitmap from a path string?

Tags: c++, gdi+

I am using the GDI+ library and I have a problem. I want to use a string variable to load a`Bitmap` variable. I don't know how to call it because I am new with this library.

My program is just taking the `image.bmp` path inside a string variable:

```cpp
string username()
{
    char username[UNLEN + 1];
    DWORD username_len = UNLEN + 1;
    GetUserName(username, &username_len);
    string pcuser = username;
    return pcuser;
}

int main()
{
    Gdiplus::Bitmap bmp("C:\\Users\\" + username() + "\\Documents\\Visual Studio Things\\image.bmp");
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to use `.c_str()` with the `username()` but this is not working. Any suggestions?

I'm getting this error:

```
Error (active)  E0289   no instance of constructor "Gdiplus::Bitmap::Bitmap" matches the argument list                  argument types are: (std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>)
```

So, how can I use `username()` to load a `Bitmap`?

Comment: Bitmap takes first parameter as pointer to WCHAR - it is wide-char. Use `wchar_t` instead of `char`, call `GetUserNameW` and replace `string` by `wstring`. Then define `fileName` as follows `wstring fileName = L"C:\\Users\\" + username() + L"\\Documents\\Visual Studio Things\\image.bmp")` and call ctor: `Bitmap bmp(fileName.c_str());`

Comment: @rafix07  Hey, i tried like this `string username()
{
 wchar_t username[UNLEN + 1];
 DWORD username_len = UNLEN + 1;
 GetUserNameW(username, &username_len);
 wstring pcuser = username;
}

int main()
{
 wstring fileName = L"C:\\Users\\" + username() + L"\\Documents\\Visual Studio";
 Gdiplus::Bitmap bmp(fileName.c_str());
 return 0;
}` Does not working for me, and why i cant get new line in this website ??

Comment: Your function returns `string` instead of `wstring`.

Comment: @rafix07 Thank you very much, its working. i learned something new!

Comment: This whole `GetUserName()` approach is the wrong way to get the path to the user's `Documents` folder anyway. Use `SHGetFolderPathW(CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS)` or `SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Documents)` instead. The user can customize the location of various "special" folders, like `Documents`. The OS knows where they are, so just ask it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You are wrong, the GetUserName function is taking the username of the pc, like this C:\\Users\\ * username * \\Documents\\

Comment: @CodingUniversity I am not wrong. The `Documents` folder is not located at `C:\Users\<username>\Documents` on *every* machine. That is the *default* path on *recent* versions of Windows, but older versions used a  very different path, and Microsoft is free to change the default path again in future versions. And like I said, the path is user customizable, too. The actual path is stored in the Registry, there are APIs *specifically designed* to get that *actual* path on *every* machine. Use those APIs to get the *real* path, don't *assume* you know where the path is, you will be wrong at times.

Comment: @RemyLebeau No, you dont understood what i said, the Getusername function is just taking the *username* like this 'C:\\Users\\ * username*\\.

Comment: @CodingUniversity I know what you are saying. You are not understanding what I am saying. User profiles are not always located at `C:\Users`. The `Documents` folder is not always located inside a user's profile, and is not always named `"Documents"`. The Shell API knows where user-specific folders are located, including the `Documents` folder. That *includes* the username in the path for you when appropriate. You SHOULD NOT build user-specific paths manually in your code, as such paths vary for different users on different machines. Ask the OS for such paths instead. I'm done debating this.

Comment: @CodingUniversity see the answer I just posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Bitmap` constructor you are trying to call takes a `const wchar_t*` as input, not a `const char*`, so you need to use `std::wstring` instead of `std::string`, eg:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplusheaders.h>
#include <string>

wstring username()
{
    wstring pcuser;
    wchar_t username[UNLEN + 1];
    DWORD username_len = UNLEN + 1;

    if (GetUserNameW(username, &username_len))
        pcuser.assign(username, username_len-1);

    return pcuser;
}

void doWork()
{
    wstring path = L"C:\\Users\\" + username() + L"\\Documents\\Visual Studio Things\\image.bmp";
    Gdiplus::Bitmap bmp(path.c_str());
    ...
} 

int main()
{
    GdiplusStartupInput input;
    ULONG_PTR token;

    GdiplusStartup(&token, &input, NULL);

    doWork();

    GdiplusShutdown(token);

    return 0;
}
```

That being said, using `GetUserName()` to build up a path to the user's `Documents` folder is the wrong way to go.  User profiles are not always located at `C:\Users\` on every machine. The user's `Documents` folder is not always located inside the user's profile, and is not always named `"Documents"`. The path can be customized by users, so it could literally be located *anywhere* on the machine.

You SHOULD NOT build up such paths manually in your code. The Shell API has [`SHGetFolderPath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpathw) and [`SHGetKnownFolderPath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath) functions that are *specifically designed* to know where pre-defined system folders and user-specific folders are located, including the user's `Documents` folder. Use those APIs to get the *real* path, don't *assume* you know where the path is, you WILL be wrong sometimes.

For example:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <Shlobj.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>
#include <gdiplusheaders.h>
#include <string>

wstring userdocs()
{
    wstring pcdocs;
    wchar_t path[MAX_PATH];

    if (SHGetFolderPathW(NULL, CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, path) == S_OK) 
    {
        if (PathAddBackslashW(path))
            pcdocs = path;
    }

    return pcdocs;
}

void doWork()
{
    wstring path = userdocs();
    if (path.empty()) return;
    path += L"Visual Studio Things\\image.bmp";

    Gdiplus::Bitmap bmp(path.c_str());
    ...
}

int main()
{
    GdiplusStartupInput input;
    ULONG_PTR token;

    GdiplusStartup(&token, &input, NULL);

    doWork();

    GdiplusShutdown(token);

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
wstring userdocs()
{
    wstring pcdocs;
    wchar_t *path;

    if (SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Documents, 0, NULL, &path) == S_OK)
    {
        pcdocs = path;
        pcdocs += L"\\";
        CoTaskMemFree(path);
    }

    return pcdocs;
}
```